# Se corta enlace web al enviarlo por whatsapp usando php (whatsapp://send?text=)

Tags: php, html5, whatsapp

Alguien tendra alguna idea de como solucionar este problema??
Gracias.

Mensaje:
Clic Aqui---> ht tp://www.m i do m i n i o.com.mx/contrato.php?T1=Ignacio Huerta
[image: Anexo imagen del mensaje]

Comment: Necesitas dar más contexto de lo que quieres hacer. Ej. ese dominio de donde lo obtienes? el parámetro T1 es dinámico (puede cambiar)

Answer (score 0):

hay que ver el código completo para ver que sucede.... pero estimo que no estas usando el a.

```
  click aquí <a href="ht tp://www.m i do m i n i o.com.mx/contrato.php?T1=Ignacio Huerta"> ht tp://www.m i do m i n i o.com.mx/contrato.php?T1=Ignacio Huerta</a>
```

Comment: o lo lógico <a href="ht tp://www.m i do m i n i o.com.mx/contrato.php?T1=Ignacio Huerta">Click Aquí </a>

Comment: echo "<a href='whatsapp://send?text=Clic%20Aqui--->%20http://$host$url'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'></i></a>";

Comment: ignacio, deberías ver como se programa en html, porque el error es conceptual de como se programa en html... la solución es la anterior, pero debes ver profundamente como se programa en html.